# Can you help me rotate the ship so that it fires from left side of screen?(its head should point right not up)

Tags: python, pygame

**alien invasion**

This is the main program, it has an instance called `ai_settings` with width,height,and background color as attributes.Screen(surface) is created then in the main while loop we check for  key events(gf.check_events),then update the ships location and the bullets location and finally draw the screen.

```
import pygame
import sys
from Settings import Settings
from pygame.sprite import Group
from Ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
def run_game():
  ai_settings=Settings(1200,800,(230,230,230))
  screen=pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,
  ai_settings.screen_height))
  pygame.display.set_caption('left spacecrafr')
  ship=Ship(screen,ai_settings)
  bullets=Group()
  while (True):
    gf.check_events(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)
    ship.update()
    gf.update_bullets(bullets,ship)
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)
run_game()
```

**Ship**

This has an initializer to create an instance and then set its current location and coordinates.Update function updates the ship's location according to key events not allowing the ship to disappear off the screen.
`blitme` function draws the ship.

```
import sys 
import pygame
class Ship():
  def __init__(self,screen,ai_settings):
     self.screen=screen
     self.ai_settings=ai_settings
     self.image=pygame.image.load('/Users/WIN-10/Desktop/alien 
     invasion/spacecraft.bmp')
     self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
     self.screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
     self.speed_factor=self.ai_settings.ship_speed
     'initializes the location of the ship and its coordinates'
     self.rect.left=0
     self.rect.centery=self.screen_rect.centery
     self.centerx=float(self.rect.centerx)
     self.centery=float(self.rect.centery)
    'flags for key events'
     self.moving_left=False
     self.moving_right=False
     self.moving_up=False
     self.moving_down=False
    
    
  def update(self):
     'sets new location for ship,it never disappears from the screen'
     if self.moving_left and self.rect.left>0:
        self.centerx-=self.speed_factor
     if self.moving_right and self.rect.right<self.screen_rect.right:
        self.centerx+=self.speed_factor
     if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom<self.screen_rect.bottom:
        self.centery+=self.speed_factor
     if self.moving_up and self.rect.top>self.screen_rect.top:
        self.centery-=self.speed_factor
     self.rect.centerx=self.centerx
     self.rect.centery=self.centery
  def blitme(self):

   '''draws the ship'''
    self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

[image]

Comment: No. Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You'll learn that we require a little more effort from your side. Please [edit] your question to add the missing parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame has a `transform` method which allows you to rotate an image

```
rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, -self.heading)
```

`self.heading` is the angle to rotate the image by.

If you are a beginner, you may find that "Pygame Zero" makes things a little easier. The Pygame Zero's `Actor` class has an `angle` property which will do all the hard work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much,the ship was rotated but what about the bullets(rectangles)?When i try to rotate rectangles,I get the following error                                                                                                                                                      rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.rect, -90)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect

Comment: Personally, I'd try making an image to represent the bullets rather than drawing a rectangle. Not sure if you can rotate rectangles.You can change their position/size (and therefore what direction they travel) however

Comment: My problem was solved by increasing the width of the rectangles thus they appeared moving to the right,however I will try to read more about rotating rectangles.Thank you